# ionic/angular project cloned using git serving from wrong branch

Tags: javascript, angular, git, ionic-framework

I cloned a branch from terminal and then checked out dev branch (was originally master). However, when I do `ionic serve` it is opening the qa branch not dev (I know because the login page for QA says so).This is so weird and has never happened before. Has anyone faced similar problems or knows how to solve this?

Comment: Question is not able to point out the exact problem you are facing, please consider editing the question.

Comment: @Wolfack I'm not sure what the exact problem is. I'm in the dev branch and it is running qa branch when I do ionic serve, which makes no sense to me. I can provide more details if you can tell me exactly what